# How can I put "unassigned" when on delete in cascade instead of leaving it in null in an entity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, bbdb

Hello how can I put "unassigned" value on a table that has a join with cascade on delete with an other table instead of leaving it in null in an entity?

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentName")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unassigned"?

Comment: Which is the type of the field?

Comment: The type of the field is string and instead of blank i want to put the string "unassigned"

Comment: The type of the field can't possibly be string. It's a OneToMany, so it refers to Many entities. I have no idea of what you're asking. You need to seriously elaborate. I just have the feeling that you're mixing presentation considerations (displaying some message when a condition is true), with persistence considerations.

Comment: there are two tables for example users with a column department_name and  an other table department if I delete a department I want all users that have that department_name(foreign key in users) to instead of null  put "unassigned" is that posible?

Comment: Why do you need to put "unassigned" instead of null?? (What are you expecting to resolve with this?) I'm asking you because we can find may be a better approach... by the way, if the departament name column at User is really a FK, and you database checks integrity, you will need a "unassigned" department...